# Could not invoke task "distillery.release"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, distillery, edeliver

I'm working through a couple of different How-Tos (the main in the project plus several via Google search) for edeliver to deploy code but I can't find a solution to this `Could not invoke task "distillery.release": 1 error found!` problem:

```sh
$ mix edeliver build release

BUILDING RELEASE OF HELLO_WORLD APP ON BUILD HOST

-----> Authorizing hosts
-----> Ensuring hosts are ready to accept git pushes
-----> Pushing new commits with git to: abc@company.com
-----> Resetting remote hosts to b8a7e8d2098b228f693352a0ebc59fa5c708f7a3
-----> Cleaning generated files from last build
-----> Updating git submodules
-----> Fetching / Updating dependencies
-----> Compiling sources
-----> Generating release
using mix to generate release
** (Mix) Could not invoke task "distillery.release": 1 error found!
--verbosity : Unknown option

A remote command failed on:

  abc@company.com

Output of the command is shown above and the command executed
on that host is printed below for debugging purposes:

FAILED with exit status 1:

    [ -f ~/.profile ] && source ~/.profile
    set -e
    cd /tmp/erlang/hello-world/builds
    if [ "mix" = "rebar" ]; then
      echo "using rebar to generate release"
      ./rebar   -f generate
    elif [ "mix" = "relx" ]; then
      echo "using relx to generate release"
      ./relx release
    elif [ "mix" = "mix" ]; then
      echo "using mix to generate release"
      MIX_ENV="prod" LINK_SYS_CONFIG="" LINK_VM_ARGS="" APP="hello_world" AUTO_VERSION="commit-count+git-revision+branch-unless-master" BRANCH="master" SKIP_RELUP_MODIFICATIONS="" RELUP_MODIFICATION_MODULE="" USING_DISTILLERY="" mix do release.version ,  distillery.release --verbosity=verbose
    fi
```

## The setup

- Erlang 22
- Elixir 1.10.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 21)

```sh
$ mix phx.new hello_world --no-ecto
```

**mix.exs**

```
...
  def application do
    [
      mod: {HelloWorld.Application, []},
      extra_applications: [:logger, :runtime_tools, :edeliver]
    ]
  end
...
  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.4.16"},
      {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.1"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.11"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.0"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"},
      {:edeliver, ">= 1.8.0"},
      {:distillery, "~> 2.1", warn_missing: false}
    ]
  end
...
```

**.deliver/config**

```
APP="hello_world" # name of your release

# The applicationis build here:
BUILD_HOST="www.hello-world.de" # host where to build the release
BUILD_USER="deployer" # local user at build host
BUILD_AT="/tmp/erlang/hello-world/builds" # build directory on build host

# Staging
STAGING_HOSTS=""
STAGING_USER=""

# This is the place where it's going to be hosted:
PRODUCTION_HOSTS="www.hello-world.de" # deploy / production hosts separated by space
PRODUCTION_USER="deployer" # local user at deploy hosts
DELIVER_TO="/home/deployer/phoenix-systems" # deploy directory on production hosts

AUTO_VERSION=commit-count+git-revision+branch-unless-master # https://github.com/edeliver/edeliver/wiki/Auto-Versioning


# For *Phoenix* projects, symlink prod.secret.exs to our tmp source
pre_erlang_get_and_update_deps() {
  local _prod_secret_path="/home/deployer/hello-world.prod.secret.exs"
  if [ "$TARGET_MIX_ENV" = "prod" ]; then
    __sync_remote "
      ln -sfn '$_prod_secret_path' '$BUILD_AT/config/prod.secret.exs'
    "
  fi
}
```

Misc:

```sh
$ mix do deps.get, compile
$ echo ".deliver/releases/" >> .gitignore
$ git init
$ git add -a
$ git commit -m "Setting up edeliver"
```

I copy the `/home/deployer/hello-world.prod.secret.exs` to the build and production server.

```sh
$ mix release.init
* creating rel/vm.args.eex
* creating rel/env.sh.eex
* creating rel/env.bat.eex
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "release config"
```

Than I start `mix edeliver build release` and get the error.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant lines are:

```
** (Mix) Could not invoke task "distillery.release": 1 error found!
--verbosity : Unknown option
```

As `--verbosity` option was [deprecated](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/6700edb017804e51aec14dedb8df888d1db4e63c/docs/upgrading_to_2_0.md#deprecations) in `v2`.

Per distillery documentation:

> The `--verbosity` flag no longer exists, use `--silent`, `--quiet` or `--verbose`.

It sees the unrecognized option and fails. Unfortunately, it happens to appear in the shell script provided by `delivery` itself (right? or is it yours?).

```
MIX_ENV="prod" [...] mix do release.version ,  distillery.release --verbosity=verbose
```

In any case, there seems to be some mess on the build server. I am not sure why it happens to be inconsistent, but maybe full cleanup would help.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very easy:

1. Run `mix distillery.init`
2. `APP` variable in `.deliver/config` must be same as release atom in `rel/config.exs`.

Answer (score -1):

Adding this file followed by a `git add . && git commit -m "test"` solves the problem.

Solves = Is a work around.

**rel/config**

```
# Import all plugins from `rel/plugins`
# They can then be used by adding `plugin MyPlugin` to
# either an environment, or release definition, where
# `MyPlugin` is the name of the plugin module.
~w(rel plugins *.exs)
|> Path.join()
|> Path.wildcard()
|> Enum.map(&Code.eval_file(&1))

use Distillery.Releases.Config,
    # This sets the default release built by `mix distillery.release`
    default_release: :hello_world,
    # This sets the default environment used by `mix distillery.release`
    default_environment: Mix.env()

# For a full list of config options for both releases
# and environments, visit https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/config/distillery.html


# You may define one or more environments in this file,
# an environment's settings will override those of a release
# when building in that environment, this combination of release
# and environment configuration is called a profile

environment :dev do
  # If you are running Phoenix, you should make sure that
  # server: true is set and the code reloader is disabled,
  # even in dev mode.
  # It is recommended that you build with MIX_ENV=prod and pass
  # the --env flag to Distillery explicitly if you want to use
  # dev mode.
  set dev_mode: true
  set include_erts: false
  set cookie: :"BNCsY8N!n{HeSZ[e_;mefm[~h>}|cU)0e6gJvkV5oh;Die$e:UC/O>Uh*6hG|<k("
end

environment :prod do
  set include_erts: true
  set include_src: false
  set cookie: :"?4t`!aFwp]@4zosVIBfaIG.^u(BX^nS=Rq}v2u&v0;mRvABjI.TdP*QLKo$rYpa="
end

# You may define one or more releases in this file.
# If you have not set a default release, or selected one
# when running `mix distillery.release`, the first release in the file
# will be used by default

release :hello_world do
  set version: current_version(:hello_world)
  set applications: [
    :runtime_tools
  ]
end
```

Comment: I doubt this could fix the issue on its own. It seems it triggered some update on the build server, or something similar.

Comment: You are right. It is not a fix. But a work around until the bug is fixed.